# The method getTimeZone(String) is undefined for the type TimeZone

Tags: java

Need some help in this code.

```
SimpleDateFormat gmtDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyy");
gmtDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+05:30"));
String time = gmtDateFormat.format(new Date());
subject = subject+" - "+time;
```

its showing error in getTimeZone as "The method getTimeZone(String) is undefined for the type TimeZone". I am using package for this is "import com.google.type.TimeZone;".

Please help me in rectifying this error.

Comment: "I am using package for this is "import com.google.type.TimeZone;" - are you sure that's the one you should be using? I suspect you actually want to be using java.util.TimeZone. Ideally, you'd actually use the java.time package instead.

Comment: @Hulk: See https://github.com/googleapis/java-common-protos. It contains common protos used in Google APIs. See https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/tree/master/google/type for the protos in google.type.